# Chrome Print CSS image not resizing

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a basic setup to center an oversized image in it's container. It works perfectly except when you try and print Chrome (Printing in FF and IE works as expected). Instead, Chrome's print preview will not resize the image at all.

Annoyingly I am unable to recreate the problem, so I hope someone might be able to suggest something it could be?

This is the basic setup:
https://jsfiddle.net/aed2gh3w/

```
<style>
.container {
  position:relative;
  width:20%;
  padding-bottom:20%;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:0 auto;

}

.align {
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin:0 -400px;
  top:0;
  width:800px;
  height:100%;
  border:none;
  text-align:center;
}

img {
  vertical-align:top;
  height:100%;
  width:auto;
}

</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="align">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works fine for me

Comment: @paolo.basso99 I am unable to replicate the problem outside my full code, so I am looking for suggestions to what might be causing it?

Comment: Any chance that this solution might work for you?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396682/window-with-image-print-issue-in-chrome

Comment: @user500665 You could post your full code then, as paolo mentioned if you go to https://jsfiddle.net/aed2gh3w/embedded/result/ the print preview seems fine on Chrome 54.0.

Comment: Print preview looks fine for me too.

Comment: Here's a related discussion for older versions of Chrome http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603491/how-to-make-html-pages-print-at-a-consistent-size-from-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was because I didn't have a height set for `.container`
Even though there is no height, because it's all padding, I still needed to add `height:0;` to it's style or else Chrome would get confused half of the time.