# Printed page size not the same in different browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am trying to create a document that prints at the same size in different browsers, but I am not having any luck.

Google Chrome 66
[image: Chrome66]

Firefox 60
[image: Firefox60]

Internet Explorer 11
[image: IE11]

(Microsoft Edge does not print background colors, so I am purposefully ignoring it.)

Why are they all different, and can I fix this? (Using CSS preferably.)

I'm guessing I will need to use `@media print` somehow, but I'm not real familiar with it.

Thanks.

Comment: May I ask if you already apply a reset CSS to this page of your?

Comment: I don't know what a reset CSS is, sorry.

Comment: It's a css file to include in your web page to set the styles of all elements to a consistent one between all browsers. In the other way, we can say that it override browsers styles.
May you give it a try to include this reset css file first top of your web page?
I usually use normalize.css https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: That is interesting, but the effect is very very minor in this case.

Comment: If things do not get prettier, you should consider using @media & @page. 
The usage is like an `if` statement (at least that is one way to understand it) and the CSS code inside that `@media print { .... }` will be affected if you enter print mode. You can refer to this example (https://github.com/randalmaia/print-css-reset/blob/master/print.css)

Comment: @Sandeep suggested this as well, but the example he gave is not handled in the same way by the different browsers.

Comment: in that case, I think you can write a small reset CSS yourselves on elements that got different styles & then using prefix of the browser to target the right one.

Comment: Could you describe what a prefix is?

Comment: Actually it's called `vendor prefix`. I missed the `vendor` part. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix

Answer (score -3):

Please go through this query-solving reply.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25248089/9628414
```

Comment: I've tried this, but the results are different in different browsers. Chrome adds its own margins to the ones specified in CSS. IE11 seems to ignore them completely.

Comment: Also, the answer you linked to is for Google Chrome only.