# Best way to print data to a HTML Template?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, templates

I'm making a website where teachers can print data from a database to a cert template. The template is already printed on existing paper then the teachers print over the template with the data. I have used CSS to push all of the Fields to the aline with the paper so it's in the correct spot when printed and works for my computer, on the browser that I use (Chrome) if I was to do it from safari or form a different computer it would be in the wrong location.

I sorry if this is a bad explanation of what I'm trying to do but I can't think of any way to print the data to the template.

any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't quite understand what you want to do, but I hope this links might share some light:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

[Printed page size not the same in different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50558648/printed-page-size-not-the-same-in-different-browsers)

And yes different browser have different pre-made settings but from what I saw, using `@page` and `@media` is the way to go when encountering this kind of problems.